# Delphi cannot remove children from VertScrollBox

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a `TVertScrollBox` control with a TRectangle inside. When I click a button I take that rectangle and I copy it 20 times inside the scroll box.

```
// var Rectangle: TRectangle;
VertScrollBox.BeginUpdate;
for i := 0 to 19 do
  begin

    //Copy the rectangle that is already inside the ScrollBox
    Rectangle:= TRectangle(RectangleTemplate.Clone(VertScrollBox));
    VertScrollBox.AddObject(Rectangle);

  end;
VertScrollBox.EndUpdate;
```

So the situation looks like this:

[image]

---

**Problem**

When I press another button I need to delete every rectangle in the scroll bot **except** the first one.

[image]

I am doing the reverse operation. In order to do this I have taken the code from an answer found in SO which states that I should run the loop backwards:

```
for j := VertScrollBox.ChildrenCount-1 downto 1 do
  if (VertScrollBox.Children[j] is TRectangle) then
    VertScrollBox.RemoveObject(VertScrollBox.Children[j]);
```

This code doesn't work because rectangles aren't deleted. Is that because I haven't set a `Parent` for the rectangle when adding it?

I've also tried something like `RemoveObject(TRectangleVertScrollBox.Children[j]))` but still nothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`VertScrollBox.AddObject` method adds controls to the inner scroll box `Content` control. You have to iterate through `Content` children in order to remove added controls.

```
for j := VertScrollBox.Content.ChildrenCount-1 downto 1 do
  if (VertScrollBox.Content.Children[j] is TRectangle) then
    VertScrollBox.Content.RemoveObject(VertScrollBox.Content.Children[j]);
```

---

Object classes and particular object instances that are not added to the `Content`, but to scroll box itself are:

- FContent
- ResourceLink
- TEffect instances
- TAnimation instances
- FVScrollInfo[0].Scroll
- FVScrollInfo[1].Scroll
- FHScrollInfo[0].Scroll
- FHScrollInfo[1].Scroll
- FSizeGrip

Comment: I mean, Rectangles are deleted from the scroll box but the space that they occupied is still there, so you can scroll down the box but you see nothing

Comment: Fixed... forgot to call VertScrollBox.Content.RemoveObject

Answer (score 0):

VertScrollBox.Content.DeleteChildren